# Point authRoute directly to google auth

Tags: haskell, yesod

Since I'm only using google auth anyways, I would like to get rid of the login screen seeing as it's quite superfluous to have a page with just a google button on.

What would be the way (if possible) to set the `authRoute` to point directly to google auth instead of pointing to the `Just $ AuthR LoginR`? It didn't seem super simple since it involved some POST request, but I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to redirect to the [forwardUrl](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/yesod-auth/Yesod-Auth-GoogleEmail.html) for Google Email:

```
Just $ AuthR Yesod.Auth.GoogleEmail.forwardUrl
```