# Using Yesod's GoogleEmail2 auth without redirect page

Tags: haskell, authentication, yesod

I have a project that uses Yesod with the module Yesod.Auth.GoogleEmail2.  In my hamlet file I have `{AuthR LoginR}` which generates the Login button.  When that button is clicked, it redirects me to /auth/login, which is a bare page that has a link that says "Login with Google".  That link takes me to /auth/page/googleemail2/forward, and then I can log in to Google and everything works great.

I'd like to remove the intermediate page /auth/login, so the user clicks the Login button and is taken directly to the Google login.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for `AuthR` [`forwardUrl`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.6/yesod-auth-1.4.13.3/src/Yesod-Auth-GoogleEmail2.html#forwardUrl)?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  For reference, I found the exact answer at [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094784/point-authroute-directly-to-google-auth/21098838#21098838) you answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Point authRoute directly to google auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094784/point-authroute-directly-to-google-auth)